# How to reduce/reuse the css I write?

Tags: css

In a page I write css many of which is same.

for example:

```
.avator img{
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
}

.title img{
width:100%;
line-height:0px;
}
```

many css have same one.

how to build them to get the smallest file?

Comment: FYI, this dosent looks like same style. Any way you can use comma (,) to group classes. Eg.  `.avator img, .title img{ your_style }`

Answer (score 1):

Using raw `css`

```
.avator img,
.title img{/* your css */}
```

Using `scss` or `sass`

```
.avator,
.title{
    img{/* your css */}
}
```

[scss/sass/less online tools](https://www.sass2css.online/).

you can use separated `class` for `elements`

```
.responsive-image{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* For responsive image */
.full-image{
    width: 100%; /* Full width image using css */
}
.mt-10{
    margin-top: 10px; /* Margin top css for all elements */
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight: bold;}
p{font-weight: normal;}
```

**Usage**:

```
<img alt="Image title" class="full-image mt-10" src="your image file name with extension" />
```

> Note: Try to write reusable css class. You can read blow links

https://medium.com/@afrench53198/reusable-maintainable-and-modular-css-b0ffedf1c208

https://medium.com/insider-inc-engineering/delightful-ways-to-write-reusable-css-using-subclasses-903e90c9cf87

https://css-tricks.com/crafting-reusable-html-templates/

Comment: @new programmer If you don't want to integrate `scss/sass` in your project but want to generate `css` using `scss/sass`. You can use this online tool called [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Comment: I mean I already have this code.and want to format it not want to write it again using your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **utility classes**. Refer following examples.

```
.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.m-t-10 {
  Margin-top: 10px;
}

.l-h-0 {
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

You can **reuse these utility classes in your HTML** as below.

```
<p class="post-title m-t-10 l-h-0">Post Title</p>

<div class="card-item width-100 m-t-10">Card Contents</div>
```

Hopefully you can save many lines in your css file.